# Switching boundaries in integrals from cartesian to polar coordinates

Tags: calculus

I have "curves" inequalities so that:

$ x^2 +y^2 ⩾  y$
 $x^2+y^2 ⩽2y$ 
 and $x⩾0$
Can u tell me how to switch those into polars ? I have tried with $x=r\cos a,\ y=r\sin a +0.5$ but i cant draw any conclusion about  lower boundary of new coordinate "r"

Comment: Why not try substituting into your inequalities:  $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$?

Comment: Why do you have the $.05$ in the equation for $y$?  Also, do you really have $x^2+y^2\leq2y$?  This means $(x-y)^2\leq0$.

Comment: $(x-y)^2 =x^2+y^2-2xy$ that is not equal $x^2+y^2-2y$

Comment: Moreover both of these equations are circle equations

Comment: mjw, if i do it, from first inequation i get $ r^2-rsina⩾1/4$, when i solve it, it looks awful and i have my integral function $xy^2$ in polar i got $r^3 *(sina)^2 *cosa$, so when i integrate in respect of r i get $r^4/4 *(sina)^2*cosa$ and i have to substitute that with this awful part

Comment: any ideas guys ?